# Behavioural change in scoped storage on Android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage, android-11

I started working on the SDK migration to 29.

The main issue that I had with this was that the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` was deprecated and scoped storage.

I had it all replaced with `Context# getExternalFilesDir(null)`. It started working on Pixel 3a with Android 11 beta.

But when I tested it on Samsung s9+ with Android 10. It started giving me this error:

```
W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg with size [96x96]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There were 3 causes:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.nio.ByteBuffer, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
      Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
      Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor, LOCAL
    There was 1 cause:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException(open failed: EACCES (Permission denied))
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
        Cause (1 of 1): class java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I was trying to load an image with the help of **Glide**.

I tested it on other devices as well. It's NOT working only on Android 10 devices. It's working on devices with Android 9 and below and Android 11 Beta.

Then, I placed the `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = "true"` in my manifest and it started working on Android 10 as well.

**Now my questions are:**

- If it is related to Scoped storage than why is it working on Android 11 and not Android 10?
- Do we only need the legacy flag for Android 10 to make this work?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/UHD Wallpapers/_uhdarchitecture208.jpg`. That is clearly not a path of getExternalFilesDir(). Where are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using a third-party library to select the images from the gallery. It requires me to give it a file path ( which I'm giving it using getExternalFilesDir() ) and it returns me the file path required.

Comment: I also had this concern that this library is returning me the old path. That's why I'm asking why is it working on Android 11 then?

Comment: Did you forget requesting read storage  permissions on Android Q? And added runtime code ?

Comment: Nope. I have the permissions added in Manifest and I was asking for run time permissions as well before this migration as it was required above Android Marshmellow.

Comment: But then that FileNotFoundException could mean that the file was not found. Did you check with a file manager app on your device?

Comment: Yes. It is available. And I can access the same file on the Android 11 device and all other devices except this Android 10 device. And the file is not corrupt, because after adding the flag, I can access it on same Android 10 device as well.

Comment: i have the same issue, any news about your question and answers ?

Comment: I found nothing regarding this. So I ended up migrating to use Scoped Storage.